# Problem with training stylegan3 - got stuck on Setting up PyTorch plugin "upfirdn2d_plugin"

Tags: multiprocess, gpu-shared-memory, stylegan

I faced a problem on training stylegan3 where the terminal stuck at "Setting up PyTorch plugin "upfirdn2d_plugin"... ". I have tried all the methods I found, such as reinstall conda, re-download the whole stylegan3 to retrain the whole network, and pip install ninja etc,. but none of them work. I don't know if you met similar situation before, and how do you solve it? I have attached the screenshot of the problem below. Thank you so much!!!
[stylegan3 training problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iIrmw.jpg)